# React Form Datepicker not reseting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, datepicker, reset

First time post here from a junior dev.  I have not been able to get this datepicker to reset to null(back to placeholder text) when pressing the "Clear Dates" button. I have tried to clear the fields from the form and also by changing the state of the inputs but no luck. Any ideas? Thank you in advance!!

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import moment from "moment-timezone";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { CdsForm, CdsDateField } from "internal-design";
import * as yup from "yup";

const DateRangePicker = ({
  startDate,
  setStartDate,
  endDate,
  setEndDate,
  submit,
  handleClearDate,
  handleSearchDates,
}) => {
  const [todayMinusThreeYears, setTodayMinusThreeYears] = useState();
  const [today, setToday] = useState();
  const [initialDate, setInitialDate] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setInitialDate(null)
    },[])

  const onChangeDateHandlerStart = (value) => {
    setStartDate(moment(value).format("MM DD YYYY"));
  };
  
  const onChangeDateHandlerEnd = (value) => {
    setEndDate(moment(value).format("MM DD YYYY"));
  };

  const clearDates = async () => {
    setStartDate(null);
    setEndDate(null);
    setInitialDate();
    handleClearDate();
  };
 
  useEffect(() => {
    const currentDate = new Date();

    function subtractYears(date, years) {
      date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() - years);
      return date;
    }
    
    setTodayMinusThreeYears(subtractYears(currentDate, 3));
    setToday(new Date());
  }, []);

  const formSchema = yup.object().shape({
          startDate: yup.date().required("This date is required"),
          endDate: yup.date().required("This date is required"),
    });   

  return (
    <>
    <CdsForm schema={formSchema}>
      <div className="d-flex flex-row">
        <div className="flex-column pe-3">
          <CdsDateField
              label="From:"
              name="startDate"
              key="startDate"
              id="startDate"
              onChange={onChangeDateHandlerStart}
              initialDate={initialDate}
              showIcon={true}
              placeholder={"mm/dd/yyyy"}
              minDate={todayMinusThreeYears}
              maxDate={today}
              >
            </CdsDateField>
        </div>
        <div className="flex-column pe-3">
          <CdsDateField
              label="To:"
              name="endDate"
              key="endDate"
              id="endDate"
              onChange={onChangeDateHandlerEnd}
              initialDate={initialDate}
              showIcon={true}
              placeholder={"mm/dd/yyyy"}
              minDate={todayMinusThreeYears}
              maxDate={today}
              >
            </CdsDateField>
        </div>
        <div className="flex-column align-self-end">
          <Button
            hasIconOnly
            type="submit"
            iconDescription="Search Work Period"
            size="md"
            kind="primary"
            onSubmit={submit}
          >
            Search
          </Button>
      </div>
      </div>

        <Button variant="link" size="sm" onClick={clearDates}>
          Clear Dates
        </Button>

      </CdsForm>
    </>
  );
};

export default DateRangePicker;
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).